# Android Connection Refused on localhost

Tags: android, connection

It's not a question but a help for everyone get Connection Refused in his Android application when access to a file on his localhost width adress like [http://127.0.0.1:8080]

Perhaps this could help anyone:

If you want to access to a file on your computer width adt emulator, don't use the default ip [127.0.0.1] cause it's the ip of the device emulator.

Add a line on your apache configuration: listen *:8080, then use your computer adress in the httpget (for example HttpGet("[http://192.168.1.1:8080]") without []). You can find your IP adress when typing ipconfig in CMD console

Sorry for some langage errors, I hope you understand me ;-)
Bye

Comment: access local host in emulatoe means use[http://10.0.2.2:8080]

Answer (score 1):

or you can use the loopback ip  **10.0.2.2**. This is useful when you're working in a team and the other members have different IPs
(--> [Referring to localhost from the emulated environment](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias))